# How do I conditionally and_call_original in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, mocking

#### The Goal

I want to use rspec to stub an object's method when passed a particular argument, but fall through to the default implementation for all other invocations.

#### What I tried

```rb
allow(Rails.cache).to receive(:write).and_call_original
expect(Rails.cache).to receive(:write).with('some_cache_key').and_raise 'a network error'
```

This results in

```
expected: ("some cache key")
     got: ("a different key")
```

I tried swapping the order of the lines in case rspec is doing an ordered search of matching stubs, but that had the same output.

I tried this:

```rb
expect(Rails.cache).to receive(:write).
  with('some_cache_key').
  and_raise('a network error').
  with(an_instance_of(String)).
  and_call_original
```

That results in

```
expected: (an instance of String)
     got: ("a different key")
```

Lastly, I tried reversing those chain parts:

```rb
expect(Rails.cache).to receive(:write).
  with(an_instance_of(String)).
  and_call_original
  with('some_cache_key').
  and_raise('a network error').
```

That results in

```
This method has already been configured to call the original implementation, and cannot be modified further.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the things I was trying is that `Rails.cache.write` takes multiple arguments and my matchers only supplied a single argument, so they never matched.

This works:

```rb
expect(Rails.cache).to receive(:write).with(cache_key, any_args).and_raise('a network error')
allow(Rails.cache).to receive(:write).with(any_args).and_call_original
```